# Populate html container based on link

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage with a container which loads different content when clicking on three possible buttons (Event, News and Others). This is achieved by using onclick on the buttons and a proper javascript function.
I'd like to craft a link to the page which is able to show the content without the user having to click the given button.

In other words, the default content shown is about News, however, there are cases in which I want to promote an event and therefore I need a link that people can click on (from outside my website) and automatically see the container with the events content.
The code I'm using, just for sake of clarity, is the following:

```
    <div style="cursor:pointer;" class="grid-cell grid-33 cell-first bg-grey-light flex-active" id="news_btn">
        <div class="cell-content one-line center font-16" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;;padding-top:0">
            <a style="display:block;width:100%;height:100%;text-decoration:none;padding-top:15px"onclick="changeTab('news')">News</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="cursor:pointer;" class="grid-cell grid-33 bg-grey-light" id="eventi_btn">
        <div class="cell-content one-line center font-16" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;;padding-top:0">
            <a style="display:block;width:100%;height:100%;text-decoration:none;padding-top:15px"onclick="changeTab('eventi')">Eventi</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="cursor:pointer;" class="grid-cell grid-33 cell-last bg-grey-light" id="cronoregue_btn">
        <div class="cell-content one-line center font-16" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;;padding-top:0">
            <a style="display:block;width:100%;height:100%;text-decoration:none;padding-top:15px"onclick="changeTab('crono_regue')">Crono Reg Ue</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The javascript function is the following:

```
function changeTab(displayTab){
    if (displayTab == 'news') {
       document.getElementById("crono_regue").className = "hide";
       document.getElementById("eventi").className = "hide";
       document.getElementById("news").className = "";  

       document.getElementById("cronoregue_btn").className = "grid-cell grid-33 bg-grey-light";
       document.getElementById("eventi_btn").className = "grid-cell grid-33 bg-grey-light";
       document.getElementById("news_btn").className = "cell-first grid-cell grid-33 bg-grey-light flex-active";    
    }
    if (displayTab == 'eventi') {
       document.getElementById("crono_regue").className = "hide";
       document.getElementById("news").className = "hide";
       document.getElementById("eventi").className = "";

       document.getElementById("cronoregue_btn").className = "grid-cell grid-33 bg-grey-light";
       document.getElementById("news_btn").className = "cell-first grid-cell grid-33 bg-grey-light";
       document.getElementById("eventi_btn").className = "grid-cell grid-33 bg-grey-light flex-active"; 
    }
    if (displayTab == 'crono_regue') {
       document.getElementById("news").className = "hide";
       document.getElementById("eventi").className = "hide";
       document.getElementById("crono_regue").className = "";   

       document.getElementById("cronoregue_btn").className = "grid-cell grid-33 bg-grey-light flex-active";
       document.getElementById("news_btn").className = "cell-first grid-cell grid-33 bg-grey-light";
       document.getElementById("eventi_btn").className = "grid-cell grid-33 bg-grey-light";
    }
}
```

I don't know whether this is achievable the way I designed my page cause I'm struggling to find a solution. I know the title I gave to the post might be to generic but I found explaining the problem only using few words hard.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Any javascript you could include will help and if possible a working sample like a jsFiddle or a jsBin would speed up the process.

Comment: How about using anchors? I mean something like `example.com/home#anchor`.

Comment: How about using `jQuery`? I find it easier to do things in it than pure JavaScript.

Comment: @afaolek how would you do it? I'm new to Javascript and Jquery so I don't really see the solution here

Comment: See my answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make the link something like `http://www.example.com#news`...

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); //Puts hash in variable, and removes the # character
    changeTab(hash);
}
```

So when the page loads, JavaScript looks up the `hash` and passes it to your function.

Comment: Welcome. You could do with [jQuery](http://jquery.com). With it, you could simplify your `changeTab` function and make it more versatile.